# proof the empirical distribution converge to distribution in probability

Tags: convergence-divergence

[As the image showed, it is a problem of proving the Glivenko-cantelli theorem, but not so complicated. For the distribution F is concentrated on three mass points which means the samples are bounded. And here the empirical distribution converge in probability.Please show the process of proof in details. Thx!!!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uN6aE.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: Let X1,X2,....Xn be i.i.d. from a distribution function F which is concentrated on
three mass points a, b and c with respective probability masses pa, pb and pc (where
pa + pb + pc = 1). Then show sup|Fn(x)-F(x)|=op(1) where the Fn(x) is the empirical  distribution